# AWS Beanstalk URL will not docket React App

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a dockerised React app to AWS Beanstalk, all the build stages passed on Travis and health check on beanstalk is ‘ok’.

Updated the Dockerfile to expose port 80. This is a Udemy course that I’m following on Docker and now the url does not work to load React.

Below is docker-file:

```
    FROM node:16-alpine as builder
    WORKDIR '/app'
    COPY package.json .
    RUN npm install
    COPY . .
    RUN npm run build
    
    FROM nginx
    EXPOSE 80
    COPY --from=builder /app/build 

    /usr/share/nginx/html
```

There’s no errors and I don’t understand what’s happened?

Comment: React on its own won't work in Elastic Beanstalk as it's a client side code (static code), you need some server side node.js like express with react to make it work.

Comment: @Sri He is using nginx. You dont need node js server

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this one and see if it's working.
It worked for me. you may change the versions if required.

```yaml
FROM node:17.1-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.22.1-alpine as prod-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```